# How to read gzipped json for Logstash input?

Tags: logstash

for json,

I could use

```
input {
  tcp {
    codec => json
  }
}
```

for gzipped content,

I could use

```
input {
  tcp {
    codec => gzip_lines
  }
}
```

How could I read gzipped json input?

My input is over network, not file...

Comment: You'd have to use the [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) in your filter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install gzip_lines plugin and use higher version of ELASTIC Stack.

**command** bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-codec-gzip_lines

see attached sample config file

```
input {
  file {
     type => "gzip"
     path => "/Users/sonupajai/Desktop/workspace/data/logs*.gz"
     mode => "read"
     file_completed_action => "log"
     file_completed_log_path => "/Users/sonupajai/Desktop/workspace/data/log.txt"
  }
}
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        target => "message"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "json-log2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Comment: My input is from network not file.. I added it to my op now.. does your solution still apply?

Comment: which elastic stack version your using?